# python - how to concatenate two words from one string without spaces

Tags: python

I have the string `name = 'one two'`. i want to make `'onetwo'` from it.

is there any cool python shortcut for it like `.join()` but without space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do `name.replace(' ','')` or `''.join(name.split())`

Answer (score 3):

You could do this by just striping all whitespace in a string:

```
name.replace(" ", "")
```

Comment: i cannot be more stupid! :D thanks man, didnot think about this way

Answer (score 2):

How about `"".join(name.split(" "))` ?

Comment: You really don't need the argument for ```split()``` (and may be better off without it

Answer (score 2):

Another one, only using one empty string and no explicit whitespace:

```
"".join('one two'.split())
```

Result:

```
'onetwo'
```